# Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'YES' to data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, case, aggregate

The following query is enumerate through about a million rows to calculate MTBUR (Mean Time Between Unscheduled Repair):

```
DECLARE @BeginDate date = '01-01-2013', 
        @EndDate date = '12-31-2013'
BEGIN
    SELECT  H.AutoType
           ,COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN (R.ReceiveDate BETWEEN @BeginDate AND @EndDate) 
                             THEN H.Hours ELSE 0 END)
                    / COUNT(CASE WHEN (R.ReceiveDate BETWEEN @BeginDate AND @EndDate) 
                          AND (R.Confirm NOT LIKE 'C%' AND R.Confirm NOT LIKE 'Y%') 
                            THEN R.Confirm ELSE 0 END)
                , SUM(H.Hours)) AS 'MTBUR'
    FROM [Hours] H
    INNER JOIN Repair R   ON H.SN = R.SN 
    GROUP BY H.AutoType
    ORDER BY AutoType ASC
END
```

I get the following error message:

```
Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'YES' to data type int.
```

I'm deducing that the `YES` from the error message is the boolean evaluation result from the first 'CASE' statement; correct me if I'm wrong.

The following is my pseudocode:

```
The numerator is the sum of all hours between @BeginDate and @EndDate
The denominator is the COUNT of all confirmed status NOT LIKE %C and NOT LIKE %Y AND between @BeginDate and @EndDate.
```

I've been tinkering with this query for days; yes, im a newbie but learning.  Would love to finish this up and move on to next sprint

Comment: What `YES` should be similar to in `INT` you think?

Comment: What data type is `R.Confirm`?

Comment: @JodyT R.Confirm is varchar

Answer (score 0):

Your case is returning an int 0 from the else, but a character from the when part, but the return type from the case must be consistent.

Try changing your case to return 1 instead of Confirm.

ie change:

```
... THEN R.Confirm ELSE 0 END), SUM(H.Hours) ...
```

To:

```
... THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), SUM(H.Hours) ...
```

And change the wrapping function from COUNT to SUM

Comment: If I substitute `R.Confirm` with `1` then how will the DBMS know to count the number of `R.Confirm NOT LIKE C% or Y%`?

Comment: If you change COUNT to SUM (as per my answer) it will work, because you will SUM over a 1 or 0, which is the same as COUNTing when it's true

Comment: I get it now...i was confused I thought I was to just count the specific column but essentially I just want to count the rows (or sum) i get it....now I'm getting divide by zero error which is what my COALESCE statement was supposed to rectify

Comment: If it works for you, wrap the sum that's sometimes returning zero in a case to check for zero and return 1 instead to prevent the divide by zero error

Answer (score 0):

```
/COUNT(CASE WHEN (R.ReceiveDate BETWEEN @BeginDate AND @EndDate) 
            AND (R.Confirm NOT LIKE 'C%' AND R.Confirm NOT LIKE 'Y%') 
            THEN R.Confirm ELSE 0 END)
```

The error actually appears to be in your 2nd case statement.
Your code implies R.Confirm is a string, yet you attempt to divide by it when your case statement is true.

So this line actually needs to be modified:  THEN R.Confirm ELSE 0 END

Answer (score 0):

Problem is, You are doing it wrongly. Your `COUNT CASE` statement should be like below. Also, notice that, `R.Confirm NOT LIKE` should be `OR` condition rather `AND`

```
SUM(CASE WHEN R.ReceiveDate BETWEEN @BeginDate AND @EndDate 
AND (R.Confirm NOT LIKE 'C%' OR R.Confirm NOT LIKE 'Y%') 
THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

Comment: If I substitute `R.Confirm` with `1` then how will the DBMS know to count the number of `R.Confirm NOT LIKE C% or Y%`?

Comment: @JeffOrris, You are confused, in your `count` you are checking condition using `CASE` and instead of counting all rows; counting only the rows which matches the CASE condition.

Comment: I want to count the rows in the `R.Confirmed` column that meets the conditions

Comment: I have read about sql...its been a long day...also, i'm not getting the right results

Comment: @JeffOrris, It was a suggestion. check the edited answer (Use `SUM` instead of `COUNT`) and Try once. If you still not getting right result then edit your post  and include what went wrong. Hope that make sense.

Comment: I get it now...i was confused I thought I was to just count the specific column but essentially I just want to count the rows (or sum) i get it....now I'm getting divide by zero error which is what my COALESCE statement was supposed to rectify

Comment: means, in denominator part none the rows matching condition. COALESCE will be of no help here.